# How to download network analyser data from browser using Protractor?

Tags: protractor

I want to download network analyser data from browser when I am executing the protractor test cases, to analyse how application is responding. Is there any way to do it using some code within protractor scripts? Please help me on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the performance logs from your webdriver browser session which often provides very useful information regarding the performance. Have a look and see if it is useful to you.

more info on the selenium logs available 
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Logging

**in your conf (capabilities or multiCapabilities)**

```
multiCapabilities: [
    {
        browserName: 'chrome',
        shardTestFiles: true,
        loggingPrefs: {
            driver: 'ALL',
            browser: 'ALL',
            performance: 'ALL',
            client: 'ALL',
            server: 'ALL'
        }
    }
],
```

**In your AfterAll**

```
afterAll(() => {
    let fs = require('fs');
    browser.manage().logs().get('performance').then(logContent => {
        // console.log(JSON.stringify(logContent, undefined, 2));

        fs.writeFile(`./results/performance_Log.txt`, JSON.stringify(logContent, undefined, 2), (err) => {
            if (err) {
                throw new Error(`Could not create log file for ${logType}`);
            }
            console.log(`performance log was created`);
        });
    })
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have already tried getting the performance logs from your webdriver browser session but it is not having the required metrics which are in HAR file, hence it does not suffice the need.

Now I am trying to use request-capture-har npm package but facing issues in it. It is throwing invalid date error. Have you used this package earlier and can provide a working code for it?

Comment: Unfortunately I have not used this package before so am unfamiliar with how exactly it works. Hope you get it working as you need